# Window Prompt() error

Tags: javascript, prompt

I do practicing Javascript for our school competition frontend category. The one function in javascript that I studying is the simple code for "Window Prompt()" . It wasn't working in my node.js with my sublime text 3. It has just an output nothing. My question is, there is missing on my code or what?

```
function myFunction(){
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");

    if (person != null) {

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
    }
}
```

Output (Nothing) :[Finished in 0.2s]

Comment: Do you ever call `myFunction`?

Comment: actually in my first code for this is , I didn't insert a function myFunction and i got an error.

Comment: C:\Users\Tongoy\Documents\Javascript\userInput.js:2
var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
             ^
ReferenceError: prompt is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous>

Comment: are you trying to run this in node.js? or WSH?

Comment: yes, I already run with node.js sir

Comment: `prompt` is not part of JavaScript, it's part of the HTML API: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#user-prompts . Node doesn't implement the HTML API (since it doesn't render HTML documents), so you cannot use it in Node. If you want a console prompt you can use readline: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

Comment: node.js doesn't have a `window` object, so there is no `window.prompt()` there.

Comment: Use something like https://jsfiddle.net/ instead of node.js for this type of task.